# SQL/DB2 Alternative to Extensive CASE Statements

Tags: sql, db2

I have a project where the data in single/multiple columns needs to be classified by group. My program uses a CASE statement to create more general categories. Since my code is quickly becoming unwieldy I don't think I have a very good approach.

How can I do better?

My Db2 query uses a 'CASE STATEMENT to generate the 'classification' column:

```
SELECT id
,plant
,CASE      
when plant like 'rose'      
 then 'flower' 
when plant like 'wildflower'
 then 'flower'
when plant like 'spruce'
 then 'tree'
when plant like 'willow'
 then 'tree'
when plant like 'peony'
 then 'flower'
when plant like 'oak'
 then 'tree'
else 'unknown'      
end as classification
FROM green_table

+----+------------+----------------+
| id | plant      | classification |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 1  | rose       | flower         |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 2  | wildflower | flower         |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 3  | spruce     | tree           |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 4  | willow     | tree           |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 5  | peony      | flower         |
+----+------------+----------------+
| 6  | oak        | tree           |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DECODE()`. It even includes an "else" case. For example:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  plant,
  decode(plant, 'rose', 'flower', 'wildflower', 'flower', 'spruce', 'tree',
                'willow', 'tree', 'peony', 'flower', 'oak', 'tree',
                'unknown') as classification
FROM green_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `join` to a derived table:

```
select g.*, coalesce(c.classification, 'unknown') as classification
from green_table g left join
     (select 'rose' as plant, 'flower' as classification from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 'wildflower' as plant, 'flower' as classification from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      . . .
     ) c
     on g.plant = c.plant;
```

I would actually recommend that you have a table called `plants` with one row per plant and the classification -- and a numeric primary key that you use to join to the name as well.

Note:  This uses string equality rather than `like`.  Equality seems sufficient and `like` will have a big impact on the performance of `join`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in operator` for listing the same category

```
SELECT id,plant,
CASE   
  when plant in ('rose','wildflower','peony') then 'flower'
  when plant in ('spruce','willow','oak') then 'tree'
else 'unknown' end as classification
FROM green_table
```

Comment: Is there a way to populate the ('rose', 'wildflower', 'peony') from another table? Could it be just a select statement querying another table?

Comment: @MatthewDavidJankowski, yes it would be select statement and then you need a join with the another table